# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'open'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this JS code:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false
        });

    $( "input[name=age]" ).change( function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).open();

        $.get( '/viewer?tool=10&age=' + $( this ).val(), function( data ) {
            $( "#dialog" ).close();            
        });
    });
});
```

When I change the value of the input of name 'age', I have this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'open'

I've correctly added the scripts to the head of my HTML document, and the call to .dialog doesn't issue any errors.

If I change the code to:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false
        });

    $( "input[name=age]" ).change( function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

        $.get( '/viewer?tool=10&age=' + $( this ).val(), function( data ) {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );            
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works fine.

How do you explain that?

Thanks!

Comment: ... because jQuery UI doesn't add an `open()` method to jQuery objects? All "methods" in jQuery UI are performed by passing parameters to the plugin (like you are doing with `dialog("open")`).

Comment: shame on me... I had the same error using the blockUI plugin, and I thought it was the same kind of error...

Answer (score 3):

A standard jQuery collection has no `open` method. jQuery UI adds a dialog method to collections which you can use to instantiate and control the dialog box.